# prevent double calendar entry on same date and time programmatically

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, calendar, recurring-events

Can [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/18086/calendar-items-at-same-time) be done programatically while saving a recurring entry?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be done but unfortunately it requires either a lot of code or the willingness to access unsupported parts of SharePoint.

Microsoft has marked both the class `Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.Calendar.OverbookChecker` and the usefull method `static bool IsOverbook(SPList list, string currentId, SPItem target, bool isTargetRecurrence)` as being Internal to Microsoft.SharePoint

Comment: Thanks! how can i do it programatically, can you please explain in detail? i am facing issues with checking booking conflict  http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/46406/check-booking-conflicts-in-sharepoint-calendar-programmatically-to-avoid-overlap
I am new to calenar list, can u please elaborate how to use the classes mentioned by you?